# How to check if User Input is present in CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, try-except

I am trying create a program that will ask for user input for a city and gender and Test their input to make sure it is valid and corresponds to values within the a CSV that has city name and different gender population.

How do I check if the userinput for both gender and city name are within the csv file. I want to create it in the way that the if the user does not put a valid year or gender. it will tell the user to choose a different city and or year.

Here is what the CSV looks like:

```
name,gen_male,gen_female
Tokyo,5000,4500
San_Francsico,400,500
Manila,600,700
New_York,8000,9000
Paris,5600,5600
Chicago,500,6000
```

Can anyone help me to figure out a way to check user input if a given value is within the csv file.

Here is my script:

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/CityGen.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    city = raw_input('Which city?:')
    gender = raw_input('What gender?:')
    yearPop = 'gen_' + year

    try:
        for row in reader:
            if row['name'] == city:
                print row[yearPop]
    except ValueError:
        print 'incorrect value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first read the csv file and save it into a dictionary with the city name as key and the value is a tuple (or maybe a named tuple?) tuple[0] is gen_male, and tuple[1] is gen_female. Then ask the user to input city's name, look it up in the dictionary, if its there, then ask him to input the gender and check if its valid for that city.

```
with open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/CityGen.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    dictionary = {}

    for row in reader:
        city = row[0]
        genders = tuple(row[1:])
        dict1 = {city: genders}
        dictionary.update(dict1)

    city = raw_input('Which city?:')
    if city in dictionary:
        gender = raw_input('What gender?:')
        if gender in dictionary[city]:
            # gender and city are valid
        else:
            # gender is not valid
    else:
        # city is not valid
```